# Firefox's "stop loading X" button. Where is similar function in Chrome for Android?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I'm using Firefox newest update and Chrome newest update on my cheap walmart LG phone. For certiain web browsing puposes I find it handy to use the "stop loading X" button on the immediate right hand of the address bar in Firefox.   On my home computer I find that the ESC keyboard button suits my needs for Chrome to stop the page from loading.  How can I perform a similar stop-loading-page in Chrome for Android on my phone?

There are only two links I've found on the web that address this. Both suggest that there ought to be an X icon to the immediate LEFT of the address bar in Chrome that appears while the page is loading that allows one to stop page.  But it is not there, anywhere, on my Chrome page on my phone.

This is very frustrating.  Nor can I find any apps or extensions to add such a function.
Any help here would be highly appreciated!
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can access this button from Chrome's menu while the page is still loading. When you would tap the three dots line the reload button would change to X button as long as the site loads.